# How can I return this array without duplicates in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I´m trying to get this array

```
 [24]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "21"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "22"
  }
```

So far I have this:

```
function Job($conn){
    $array = array();
    foreach(array_unique($_SESSION['ROLES']) as $value)
    {
        $sql="SELECT employee,task FROM table WHERE id={$value} AND employee=24";//echo($sql);
        $result = $conn->executeSQL($sql); 
        foreach($result as $value)
        {
            $array[$value['employee']][] = $value['task'];
                 
        }               
    }
      
 return $array;  
               
}
```

Which returns the tasks for two values I have store in $_SESSION['ROLES'] but if there are duplicates I need to remove them :

```
 [24]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "21"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "22"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "21"
    [3]=>
    string(1) "22"
  }
```

Comment: `$array[$value['employee']]  = array_unique($array[$value['employee']]);` -- you obviously know about `array_unique()`, since you used it in the `foreach`. Why didn't you think to use it for the result?

Comment: Thank you very much! I was trying to use `array_unique()` but in  `$value['task']`, now I see I was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways to do this.

1. Use `array_unique` as indicated by comments.

   ```
   function Job($conn) {
       $array = array();
       foreach(array_unique($_SESSION['ROLES']) as $value)
       {
           $sql="SELECT employee,task FROM table WHERE id={$value} AND employee=24";//echo($sql);
           $result = $conn->executeSQL($sql);
           $temp = [];
           foreach($result as $value)
           {
               $temp[] = $value['task'];
           }
           $array[$value['employee']] = array_unique($temp);
        }

        return $array;
    }
   ```
2. Add a conditional to the code to add the element if it does not already exist.

   ```
   function Job($conn) {
       $array = array();
       foreach(array_unique($_SESSION['ROLES']) as $value)
       {
           $sql="SELECT employee,task FROM table WHERE id={$value} AND employee=24";//echo($sql);
           $result = $conn->executeSQL($sql);
           foreach($result as $value)
           {
               if ( ! in_array($value['task'], $array[$value['employee']]) )
                   $array[$value['employee']][] = $value['task'];

           }
       }
       return $array;

    }
   ```